# Codeigniter count number of articles in one category while listing categories

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some problem while listing categories from database.

First i have a table called "Videos" where i store som videos-information like v_name, v_description and category_name.

In the second table called "Categories" where i store categories-information like c_name and c_description.

OFC i have id's in every table :)

But now i want to list the categories and in the same query count every videoitem in every category.

This is the code and i can't figure out how to do in the model now and later how to show the numbers in the view file, so pleace help me!

Thanks for your time and support :D

```
    $this->db->select('c.*');
    $this->db->from('categories as c');
    $this->db->join('videos as v', 'c.c_name = v.v_category', 'right');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL to create the two database tables? This would help to set up a fiddle/demo.

Comment: Hum... In table categories i have 3 fields:

Categories:
c_id 'num' Primary key
c_name 'text'
c_description 'text'


In second table Videos
Videos:
v_id, num, Primary Key
v_name, text
v_description, text
category_name, text

So if i have 3 cateories in the categories_table called 'Action', 'Drama', 'Thriller' i want to list this categories on page Categories.

I can list the categories without any problem, but i want to show how many videos there are in every category with help from the table Videos and the field category_name.

Comment: it's always best to update the question, rather than providing details about the question in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your code to work you need two changes:

- First you join type should be a "left join". Than way you still will get a count result  (0) even if a category has no videos yet.
- Second you need to group your results to be able to use the aggregate function count().

Try with this:

```
$this->db
->select('categories.c_name, COUNT(videos.id) as num_videos')
->from('categories')
->join('videos', 'categories.c_name = videos.v_category', 'left')
->group_by('categories.c_name');
```

Also you should reconsider your DB design. If you have id columns in both tables (wich I assume are the primary key) then you should define the relationship between the tables (foreign keys) using the id column, not the name.

Comment: how do i echo out the number?
ANd can i get more information from categories like the description?

Yes i will create a relationship between the id-fields for the future

Comment: YES - You solved it JAVI! Im very thankful for your time and support!

Comment: Yeah, solved, but how do you retrieve the video count. I've retrieved the categories successfully but the count